# C++Write specific data patterns into text file from RFID reader

Tags: c++, rfid

I successfully got data from the reader and wrote it to a text file.

Example of a detected tag: **4330-3031-3138-3031-2D32-2D31**

However, the tag data is written into the text file is like this:

```
43

4330

4330-30

4330-3031

4330-3031-31

4330-3031-3138

4330-3031-3138-30

4330-3031-3138-3031

4330-3031-3138-3031-2D

4330-3031-3138-3031-2D32

4330-3031-3138-3031-2D32-2D

4330-3031-3138-3031-2D32-2D31
```

I tried to use an if statement (count++) to write the last value which is the longest from above into the text file but somehow the data is not written to text file even the variable holds its value.

```
Below are my codes:
{
// Format Tag and print on screen

void printTagData(TAG_DATA *pTagData)

{

    fstream myTextFile,myTextFile2, myTextFile3;

    string fileText,fileText2; 

    char  tagBuffer[1024] = {0,};

    char* pTagReportData = tagBuffer;

    int   index = 0;

     int count = 0;

    TCHAR   resultBuffer[MAX_PATH]; 

    for(index = 0; index < pTagData->tagIDLength; index++)

    {
         myTextFile.open("text1.txt",ios::app);

             if (0 < index && index % 2 == 0)

             {

                 *pTagReportData++ = '-';

             }

             sprintf(pTagReportData, "%02X", pTagData->pTagID[index]);

             while (*pTagReportData) pTagReportData++;

        stringstream ss;

        ss << tagBuffer;

        ss >> fileText;

        myTextFile << fileText << endl;

        myTextFile.close(); 

    }

    _stprintf(resultBuffer, TEXT("%S"), tagBuffer);


    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hDlg, IDC_INVENTORY_LIST, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)resultBuffer);

    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hDlg, IDC_INVENTORY_LIST, WM_VSCROLL, (WPARAM)SB_BOTTOM, 0);

}
```

Please feel free to give me any tips/guidance on it.
Should I just write another code to extract the patterns that match with "4330-3031-3138-3031-2D32-2D31" and write into a new text file?

Comment: A straightforward solution would be to use `ios::out`. But then you would need to create a new text file for every tag. Another thing you could try would be to write to `myTextFile` outside the loop, just once.

Comment: Is your file writing supposed to be inside your `for` loop? I'm not sure what the point of the `stringstream` is? You could write `tagBuffer` directly into `myTextFile `

Comment: @Susmit Agrawal Thanks for the suggestions. The reason why I use ios::app is I would like to keep on adding records into the text file without remove the previous record(the reader will keep on reading the tags pass through). I had try that solution before but somehow the data is not written into the text file which make me do not know what to do with it.

Comment: @Alan Birtles Hi Alan, I tried your suggestion which move the file writing outside from the loop and it works! Thank you much appreciated bro! Btw I was using stringstream and try to use it to convert char to string then allow me to write into the text file, but now i had remove it which still works.

Answer (score 2):

This code is very convoluted.  I would do something like this (code untested and error handling omitted for clarity):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printTagData (TAG_DATA *pTagData)
{
    FILE *f = fopen ("text1.txt", "wt");
    for (int i = 0; i < pTagData->tagIDLength; i++)
    {
         if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0)
             fprintf (f, "-");
         fprintf (f, "%02X", pTagData->pTagID [i]);
    }

    fclose (f);
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the codes was originally from the SDK of the reader which also confuse me, I think the code was going to display the detected tag on the UI. I had tried your method and it work other way. Still a big appreciation for helping me. Thanks.

Comment: So my code does what you want?  If so, please accept my answer. If not then please say why not.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening, and appending to, the file inside the loop, so you get one line for each iteration.

Instead, gather the entire result first, and then write it to the file.

Here's a version that's more "not C, but C++":

```
#include <iomanip> // For 'setw' and 'hex'


void printTagData(TAG_DATA *pTagData)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(int index = 0; index < pTagData->tagIDLength; index++)
    {
         if (0 < index && index % 2 == 0)
         {
             ss << '-';
         }
         ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << pTagData->pTagID[index];
    }
    std::string tag = ss.str();
    std::ofstream myTextFile("text1.txt");
    myTextFile << tag << endl;

    TCHAR   resultBuffer[MAX_PATH]; 
    _stprintf(resultBuffer, TEXT("%S"), tag.c_str());
    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hDlg, IDC_INVENTORY_LIST, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)resultBuffer);
    SendDlgItemMessage(g_hDlg, IDC_INVENTORY_LIST, WM_VSCROLL, (WPARAM)SB_BOTTOM, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I tried your method but i dont know why it shows "namespace std has no member of setw(2) ". But i had tried others method to overcome this problem. Still a big thank you for your help.

Comment: @AhBoo Sorry, I left out an `#include` that you need. I added it. (You can search [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to figure out which header to include for standard library things.)

Comment: It is okay dude. Thanks for the help and thanks for remind me not to ask another question under a question. I did it because I am new to Stack Overflow. Sorry for that.